# Load iframe, copy, and remove iframe does not work when executed locally from PC/Windows

Tags: javascript, html

The code below works when executed from a server, but fails on my PC.
I have tried Chrome, Edge.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HTML Includes</title>

<body>
  <h1>The Simplest Ways to Handle HTML Includes</h1>
  <h3>https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/html-includes/</h3>
  <p>Load iframe, copy to &lt;div&gt; before, and remove iframe.
    <p>If the background is gray, then removing the iframe failed.
      <p>Works from server, but not from a local file.</p>
      <div></div>
      <iframe name="content" style="background-color: lightgrey; width:100%" src="fff.html" onload="this.before((this.contentDocument.body||this.contentDocument).children[0]);this.remove(); ">
    </iframe>
</body>
```

I got the following error:

```
fff.html:14 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'body')
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload (fff.html:14:143)
```

With Firefox, it works.

Comment: _"but fails on my PC"_ - is nothing written to your browser's dev console that explains why the `<iframe>` couldn't be loaded?

Comment: I bet you have access denied console errors

Comment: I forgot to mention to save the file as fff.html.

I do not see any errors.The loading of the iframe is OK.
However it is not copied, and the iframe is not deleted.

Comment: @mplungjan, No difference.

Comment: Why does the error message say the error was _in_ `fff.htm`? Are you loading the document into itself here?

Comment: Yes I did to make testing easier. But a different file gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Since your `html` document and the `iframe` inside it are both loaded with a `file:///` schema, their origin are treated as *opaque origins* as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#file_origins):

> Modern browsers usually treat the origin of files loaded using the
> `file:///` schema as *opaque origins*. What this means is that if a file
> includes other files from the same folder (say), they are not assumed
> to come from the same origin, and may trigger [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) errors.

That happens to be the case for Chrome, also Edge which uses the Chrome [Blink engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)), but not for Firefox.
Due to that, the [contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) returns `null`, as noted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument), since in this case the `iframe` and its parent document are not the [Same Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Thus, the code `this.contentDocument.body` triggers the error, not reaching the `this.remove()`, and that's why nothing works.